# Options for running a full node and simulation node

Tags: nodeos, eosio.token, mainnet

I want to integrate EOS to our exchange and I want to be able to send new EOS transactions and to follow any incoming transactions to any of my addresses.

I wonder what is the best option for this kind of tasks.

Rather than connecting to any of existing nodes, I want to run my own full node for mainnet.

Also for development purposes, I want to run my simulation net, create tokens and send between my accounts.

The options I tried;
Building EOSIO and CDT from source code, 
Installing from binaries
Running docker images,
Using EOSIO Studio UI for Mac

But for all these options, I always stuck at building eosio.token smart contract. Building this smart contract is never ending, sometimes it stuck at %83, sometimes it gives an error like ‘Warning, action XXXXX does not have a ricardian contract’

I able to run nodeos, cleos and keosd but even I would sync with mainnet I think I will need to build to deploy a smart contract to send new transaction.

I am following docs from https://developers.eos.io/eosio-home/docs

Comment: I think you are fine with the options to run a node. But something goes wrong when compiling contracts. Are you building the contract with the build.sh-script or are you trying to build them with the cdt?